# How to get authenticated user from KeycloakSession inside RealmResourceProvider

Tags: keycloak, provider, keycloak-rest-api

I am writing a Keycloak RealmResourceProvider and I need access to the currently authenticated user, I use keycloak 15.1.1 and java code provider. I am trying to implement a custom API with RealmResourceProvider

I tried with :

```
 private final AuthenticationManager.AuthResult auth;

public ExampleRestResource(KeycloakSession session) {
    this.session = session;
    this.auth = new AppAuthManager.BearerTokenAuthenticator(session).authenticate();
}
```

but the I get class not found error

```
    17:58:53,848 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/services/managers/AppAuthManager$BearerTokenAuthenticator
```

Is there any other way to access the current user from barrer token?

Comment: Have you added a dependency to keycloak-services to your classpath?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-services/15.1.1

Comment: @sventorben this is the solution please gi it as answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the following dependency on your classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
    <version>15.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You may also need to add it to your `MANIFEST.MF` file like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.keycloak.keycloak-services
```

or manage the dependency via your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file like this

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
            <!-- … -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```